# In React manage button value state for dynamically added buttons

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The code below is a small, very simplified snippet from a React messaging app

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Chat = () => {
    const [myMessages, setMyMessages] = useState([]);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
    const [myButtons, setMyButtons] = useState([{}]);

    const addNewMessage = () => {

        let buttonIndex = myMessages.length;
        setMyButtons(myButtons => [...myButtons, { value: "Copy message" }]);

        let newMessage =
            (<div>
                <div>{message}</div>
                <button className="copy-to-clipboard-button" onClick={() => { copyToClipboard(buttonIndex, message); }}>
                    {myButtons[buttonIndex].value}
                </button>
            </div>);

        setMyMessages([...myMessages, newMessage]);

    };


    const copyToClipboard = (i, text) => {
        alert("copied");
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
        let allButtons = myButtons.slice();
        allButtons[i].value = "Copied!";
        setMyButtons([...allButtons]);
    };


    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setMessage(event.target.value);
    };


    return (

        <div>
            <div style={{ maxHeight: "80vh", minHeight: "90vh", maxWidth: "96vw" }}>
                <div>{myMessages.map(message => <div>{message}</div>)}
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="message"
                        name="message"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        value={message}
                    />

                    <button onClick={addNewMessage}>Go!</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    )
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.body).render(<Chat />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

This code is for demonstration purposes only in order to spotlight the problem I'm trying to solve.  Basically, when a new message is added, a copy to clipboard button is added with it.  The value of each these dynamically added buttons is set to `{myButtons[buttonIndex].value}` with the intention that I'm tying the button's value to a state variable that can be updated and rendered.  This value is set correctly when the component is first added.

When a 'copy-to-clipboard-button' is clicked, the `copyToClipboard` method is called and the copy functionality works correctly.  The  next step is to change the button value to "Copied!".  Although the array is updated correctly, the value of the button is not updated.  I suspect that the problem is that when the button is created, it sets the value as a static value and is not tied to that state variable going forward.  My thinking is that there is a way to indicate that the button value should be tied to state ongoing, but I'm not able to find the right syntax.  Perhaps there's a better way to approach this altogether.  Looking for some guidance.  Thanks!

Comment: `myButtons` is an array of objects, so you need to replace `allButtons[i] = "Copied!"` with `allButtons[i].value = "Copied!"`.

Comment: You meant `setMyMessages([...myMessages, newMessage]);` and `setMyButtons([...allButtons])` right? Are you able to check that your minimal example doesn't have other errors/bugs that aren't part of your question? I've made you a code snippet that you can use to show us the problem easily

Comment: Thank you for posting the corrections and the snippet! Leaving off the ```.value``` was a typo, but I’ll update my code with what you have here and see if it fixes the problem I’m trying to solve. I updated my question to include your suggestions.  I'll report back tomorrow once I'm in the office.  Thanks!

Comment: The code snippet is works now...mostly.  The text for the first button is not being set.  I also added an alert box when the button click event is fired so that there's indication the button click event is firing.  The copy to clipboard functionality is not working, but I suspect that may be related to limitations of snippets.  I also tried in my local code to use a single state variable instead of an array to see if that worked and it doesn't.  I still suspect that when rendering in this manner, the button value is set once and is not tied to state going forward.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Message = ({ message, buttonIndex }) => {
  const [buttonValue, setButtonValue] = useState("Copy message");

  const copyToClipboard = (text) => {
    alert("copied");
    navigator.clipboard.writeText(text);
    setButtonValue("Copied!");
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div>{message}</div>
      <button
        className="copy-to-clipboard-button"
        onClick={() => {
          copyToClipboard(message);
        }}
      >
        {buttonValue}
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

const Chat = () => {
  const [myMessages, setMyMessages] = useState([]);
  const [message, setMessage] = useState("");

  const addNewMessage = () => {
    setMyMessages([...myMessages, message]);
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setMessage(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <div style={{ maxHeight: "80vh", minHeight: "90vh", maxWidth: "96vw" }}>
        {myMessages.map((message, index) => (
          <Message key={index} message={message} buttonIndex={index} />
        ))}
        <input type="text" id="message" name="message" onChange={handleChange} value={message} />
        <button onClick={addNewMessage}>Go!</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.body).render(<Chat />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

if i got your mean correct , create a separate component for each message and its associated button. This way, each button's value would be tied to its own state variable and can be updated independently

Comment: Thank you for the refactored code!  This seems like a better and cleaner approach!  I'm going to look into refactoring my app.  Can you tell me if you would normally place Message in it's own .js file or leave it in the same .js file with Chat?

Answer (score 1):

You need a function to trigger references:

If you use

```
  let newMessage =
            (<div>
                <div>{message}</div>
                <button className="copy-to-clipboard-button" onClick={() => { copyToClipboard(buttonIndex, message); }}>
                    {myButtons[buttonIndex].value}
                </button>
            </div>);
```

after compile:

```
  let newMessage = createElement('div', [
    createElement('div', message),
    createElement('button', {...}, [myButtons[buttonIndex].value])
  ])
```

this leads to static compilation at creation time instead use function

```
 let newMessage =
            () => {
            // scope value
            let msg = message
            return (<div>
                <div>{msg}</div>
                <button className="copy-to-clipboard-button" onClick={() => { copyToClipboard(buttonIndex, msg); }}>
                    {myButtons[buttonIndex].value}
                </button>
            </div>);
        }
```

```js
const { useState } = React;

const Chat = () => {
    const [myMessages, setMyMessages] = useState([]);
    const [message, setMessage] = useState("");
    const [myButtons, setMyButtons] = useState([{}]);

    const addNewMessage = () => {

        let buttonIndex = myButtons.length;
        const currentButton = { value: "Copy message" }
        myButtons.push(currentButton)
        setMyButtons([...myButtons])

        // you need a function to trigger references
        let newMessage =
            (myButtons) => {
            // scope value
            let msg = message
            return (<div>
                <div>{msg}</div>
                <button className="copy-to-clipboard-button" onClick={() => { copyToClipboard(currentButton, msg); }}>
                    {currentButton.value}
                </button>
            </div>);
        }

        setMyMessages([...myMessages, newMessage]);

    };


    const copyToClipboard = (currentButton, text) => {
        alert("copied "+ text);
        navigator.clipboard.writeText(text)
       currentButton.value = "Copied!";
        setMyButtons([...myButtons]);
    };


    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setMessage(event.target.value);
    };


    return (

        <div>
            <div style={{ maxHeight: "80vh", minHeight: "90vh", maxWidth: "96vw" }}>
                <div>{myMessages.map(message => <div>{message(myButtons)}</div>)}
                    <input
                        type="text"
                        id="message"
                        name="message"
                        onChange={handleChange}
                        value={message}
                    />

                    <button onClick={addNewMessage}>Go!</button>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    )
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.body).render(<Chat />);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/18.2.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/18.2.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

> I fixed some bugs in your code or use diff to see details

Comment: I have minimalized the fix but your code has many problems including `leak memory`

Comment: Yes, I see that you addressed more directly the fix in the context that I provided.  I appreciate your response and I see that it does work!  Thanks!  Can you elaborate on the memory leak issue or provide a link so that I can read into it further?

Comment: @Nimblejoe https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Memory_management  basically your old code is referencing old outdated arrays it crashes the app and worse the cleaner can't delete them

Comment: @Nimblejoe if you use js you need to make good use of referentiality instead of depending on indexes or keys

Comment: Got it. Thanks @Tachibana for the additional information!